# Dirac string and nature of singularities

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, singularities, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-string

The Dirac magnetic monopole is defined as
\begin{align}
\vec{B}=\frac{g\vec{r}}{r^3}\,,
\end{align}
where $g$ is the strength of the monopole and $\vec{r}$ a vector. It is possible to show that the magnetic field is generated by the following "north" and "south" vector potentials
\begin{align}
   A^N=\frac{g\sin\theta}{r(\cos\theta+1)}\hat{\phi}\,,\quad A^S=-\frac{g\sin\theta}{r(\cos\theta+1)}\hat{\phi}\,,
 \end{align}
respectively, which are defined everywhere except but $\theta=\pi,0$, respectively. These singularities are known as the Dirac string, and it means that we cannot define the magnetic field everywhere.

In this regard, I have two questions:

*a)* Could someone show me an illustrative draw or image where the Dirac string and the nature of the vector potentials (or the magnetic field) can be seen explicitly on it?

*b)* According to Nakahara,

> "the singularity along the $z$-axis is called the Dirac string and reflects the poor choice of the coordinate system".

I know that with gauge transformations it is possible to move the Dirac string, but it is a nonavoidable singularity (just like $r=0$ in the Schwarzschild case), or a singularity of the coordinates (just like $r=2MG$ in the Schwarzschild case, which can be "eliminated" with Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates) like Nakahara suggest? I am confused.

Comment: My answer to this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4644356/949989) is closely related to this. It also contains some visualisations.

Comment: I have just checked that the vector field $F$ I am discussing over there corresponds to the $A^N$ in your post.